# Option to add Android SDk in Unity not available

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to add Android SDK to Unity however Unity does not give me the option to add the path to the software. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
[Image of box that appears after pressing external tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRERM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to switch the build target to Android from Build Settings?